# How do i get a font to show up smooth like this?

Tags: css, fonts

Hey if you take a look at this link below

http://www.thesun.co.uk/sol/homepage/showbiz/4491771/Cheryls-been-married-she-may-hurt-my-son-Tre.html

You will notice that the title of the story, "Cheryl Cole’s been married ...she may hurt my son, Tre", is so smooth and looks like text done in photoshop, i was wondering, how does one get the font so smooth looking, I have been wanting to know this for years. Is it css or html, when i looked at their source code, it seemed to be some sort of javascript.

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: See http://www.google.com/webfonts/

Comment: looks like it's just impact font.

Comment: Mihad. Welcome to StackOverflow! (PS - don't forget to select an answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're just using a standard font (`font-family: Impact`) and making it big (`font-size: 50px`). Depending on your browser, your OS, and your own settings different fonts at different sizes can trigger anti-aliasing (that smoothing effect you like so much).

EDIT:

certain setups only "smooth" fonts larger than a certain size (Let's say 16px or higher). So, text smaller than 16px won't be smoothed for readability's sake and text 16+ px will be anti-aliased (smoothed).

Some setups don't do any anti-aliasing. Some always do anti-aliasing.

Answer (score -1):

The computed style of that live is this, I've highlighted the font-family... Maybe that's what you mean.

`-webkit-background-clip: border-box;
-webkit-background-origin: padding-box;
-webkit-background-size: auto;
-webkit-border-image: none;
background-attachment: scroll;
background-clip: border-box;
background-color: transparent;
background-image: none;
background-origin: padding-box;
background-size: auto;
border-bottom-color: black;
border-bottom-style: none;
border-bottom-width: 0px;
border-left-color: black;
border-left-style: none;
border-left-width: 0px;
border-right-color: black;
border-right-style: none;
border-right-width: 0px;
border-top-color: black;
border-top-style: none;
border-top-width: 0px;
clear: none;
color: black;
display: block;`
**`font-family: impact, helvetica, sans-serif;`**
`font-size: 50px;
font-weight: normal;
height: 100px;
line-height: 50px;
list-style-image: none;
list-style-position: outside;
list-style-type: none;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-right: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
max-width: none;
outline-color: black;
outline-style: none;
outline-width: 0px;
overflow-x: visible;
overflow-y: visible;
padding-bottom: 10px;
padding-left: 0px;
padding-right: 0px;
padding-top: 0px;
vertical-align: baseline;
width: 620px;`